# Calculate Var Args Length in C

Tags: c, mingw, mingw32, printf

I'm trying to port `asprintf()` to windows, since its a GCC library function on Linux, and doesn't exist on Windows.

I'm stuck at calculating the var args' length so I can allocate memory for them. I tried two approaches:

1. Write the var args to a file, then taking the result of the function (which is the number of bytes written = var args' length) but its silly since the user will see internal random data in his app dir
2. Use the function `vsprintf()` with NULL as first parameter (the variable to write output to) so it returns the length of var args, but this one failed because it works on XP only, Windows 7 doesn't allow writing to a NULL variable.

Any more ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`_vscprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w05tbk72%28VS.71%29.aspx) instead, it only returns the required count (not including the terminating null)